# View video/game content over remote session in realtime

Tags: windows-7, remote-desktop, remote, video-streaming, gaming

Is there any software to take full advantage of a 1Gbps LAN line to remotely view video or game content via a remote session of some sort (RTP/RDP,etc)?

Around 24-30FPS would be sufficient and a delay would be fine for video content but obviously not so much for gaming.

Some packet loss/quality drops would be fine as long as FPS remains above the bottom line (24) while maintaining an overall high bandwidth usage.

Traditional VNC type remote sessions are efficient but I'm looking for something that is both efficient (on hardware) and inefficient (on bandwidth). [proactive rather than reactive]

It would also be nice if audio was passed through in the same manner to the client PC.

At what LAN speed would this be possible if not now? 2Gbps? 10Gbps? (1080p preferred)

---

Services like ustream, twitch.tv, and onlive seem to accomplish this very well - it should be even more capable locally.

Comment: I don't know of any remote desktop clients on the market that allow HD content to be displayed that doesn't compromise the quality of the content or introduce a large amount of latency with the audio because of the latency to the content.  Video through your browser works because of your cache there isn't a reason for a remote desktop client to use a cache the packets are small enough to always be sent.

Comment: I'd recommend looking into the software people use to make those ustream, twitch.tv, etc streams.  I'd bet they can be configured to stream to another computer on your LAN.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solutions as low as 50Mbps both remote and LAN:

- Steam In-Home Streaming
- NVIDIA GameStream
- Moonlight